# Regex to filter images based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this,

```
<td class="optionsImg" style="display:none;">
    <img src="../status/approved-01.png" />
    <img src="../status/rejected-02.png" />
    <img src="../status/pending-01.png" />
</td>
```

and I am trying this,

```
var allImages = $(".optionsImg").find("img");
```

Now I need to select image that has "-02.png" in above using any possible technique, I want to keep it as short as possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [attribute-value ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to select all the images whose `src` attribute value ends with `-02.png`.

```
 $('.optionsImg img[src$="-02.png"]')
```

If you want to select images containing string **anywhere** in the value use [attribute-value contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
 $('.optionsImg img[src*="-02.png"]')
```